# Libgdx - Save system

Tags: java, android, libgdx, save

I need a system, that will store one constantly growing float to a txt-file same time when closing the program and will load the stored value from the txt-file in to the game for use when opening the program. Is json-file easier way to do this? If so, can you help me to make save system with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should use [Preferences](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences):

1. Get the `Preference` in the `create()` method: `Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("My Preferences");`
2. Read the `float` value or a default value, if there is no value yet: `float value = prefs.getFloat("Value", 0.0f);`
3. Increase it when needed.
4. Set and `flush()` it in the `dispose()` or `pause()` method: `prefs.putFloat("Value", myValue);` `prefs.flush()`

And you are done.
Of course you can also write your own `File` instead of using `Preference`s, but then it won't work on HTML5, as it does not support the `external` and `local` `FileHandle`s.

I don't understand why you want to use JSON, that makes sence only, if your have more values you want to store, so that the `File` would get more complex. For only 1 value, you don't need no format, just write the value in a `File` and read it when needed.

Just a suggestion:
I don't kow what kind of game you want to create, but as you are asking a pretty basic question, i suggest you to start with some easy games like pong or something similar.
First, read the relevant parts of the [Libgdx wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki), you don't need the 3D part, the Box2D documentation and advanced things like that.
Then read some Libgdx tutorials and start experimenting with it.
Don't rush into big projects, developing games isn't easy, it takes a lot of work and you need some experience to succeed.